# Problem: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required

Tags: python, sql, flask

i'm having the issue mentioned in the question's title while runing flask framework from python.
probably a syntax error but i can't figure it out

this is the code:

```
# do the transaction
else:

    # sustract stocks value from cash and update users table
    current_user["cash"] = current_user["cash"] - final_price
    db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :cash WHERE id = :id", cash = current_user["cash"], id = current_user["id"])


    # query database to know if current user already have at least one of the requested shares
    share_holder = dict(db.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE owner = :owner AND symbol = :symbol", owner = current_user["username"], symbol = symbol))

    # if user doesn't have any of this particular shares
    if not share_holder:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO stocks (symbol, owner, amount, users_id) VALUES (:symbol, :owner, :amount, :users_id)", symbol = symbol, owner = current_user["username"], amount = shares, users_id = current_user["id"])
        share_holder.clear()
        return render_template("buy.html")

    # if user have at least one share already
    else:
        new_shares_amount = int(share_holder["amount"]) + shares
        db.execute("UPDATE stocks SET amount = :amount WHERE id = :id", amount = new_shares_amount, id = share_holder["id"])
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

this is the problematic section where the error appears, on the line 4:

```
# if user have at least one share already
else:
    new_shares_amount = int(share_holder["amount"]) + shares
    db.execute("UPDATE stocks SET amount = :amount WHERE id = :id", amount = new_shares_amount, id = share_holder["id"])
    return render_template("buy.html")
```

thanks in advance